# How to use lambda function with the PyQt "connect" function when the widgets are instanciated in a loop?

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt5

I am creating in a PyQt project a list of widgets that depend on the situation (here it is represented with a list of widget types). I don't know by advance the number of widgets needed, neither their type nor the number of widgets for each type.

Creating them is not complicated but I am having trouble when I have to catch their new value when the user wants to change them.

Here is the minimum reproducible example of my problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QSpinBox, QWidget
import sys

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widgetList):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.widgetList = widgetList
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        for widgetNumber in range(len(widgetList)):
        
            if widgetList[widgetNumber] == 'QCheckBox':
                widget = QCheckBox()
                widget.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.argumentChanged(widgetNumber, widget.isChecked()))
            
            elif widgetList[widgetNumber] == 'QSpinBox':
                widget = QSpinBox()
                widget.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.argumentChanged(widgetNumber, widget.value()))
            
            layout.addWidget(widget)
            
        self.setLayout(layout)
    
    def argumentChanged(self, widgetNumber, value):
        print("The widget number", widgetNumber, "that is a", self.widgetList[widgetNumber], "has been modified! New value:", value)
    
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    widgetList = ['QCheckBox', 'QCheckBox', 'QSpinBox']
    widget = MyWidget(widgetList)
    widget.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window()
```

In this situation, the value of widgetNumber in the lambda functions will always be the last iteration of the loop. So if I had 4 widgets, I will have a 3 value inside every lambda function. The objective is to have the value of the current widget.

I also tried to change the expressions of the lambda functions to these:

```
lambda widgetNumber: self.argumentChanged(widgetNumber, widget.value()))
```

but the situation becomes stranger: when increasing the value of a SpinBox, the widget number is increasing, and vice-versa when decreasing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables used inside a lambda are always evaluated at execution: `widgetNumber` will *always* be the last value in the for loop.

Also, signals can have arguments, and if you use a positional argument in the lambda, that argument will be the value of that signal when it's emitted: `lambda widgetNumber:` will result in the spinbox value or the state of the check box.

If you need "static" arguments, you need to use keyword arguments. Since the signal has arguments, there's also no need to call the getter again:

```
lambda value, widgetNumber=widgetNumber: self.argumentChanged(widgetNumber, value)
```

Remember that lambdas should be preferably used only when there is no other, *simpler* (*clearer* or *cleaner*) solution.
In this case, we can use the [`sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) function provided by Qt, which returns the object that emitted the signal.

In the following example I've simplified the whole loop, and used a [custom property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#dynamic-properties) to set the number directly on the widget (note that also a basic attribute could be used, but properties are more consistent with Qt).

```py
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widgetList):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.widgetList = widgetList
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for number, widgetType in enumerate(widgetList):

            if widgetType == 'QCheckBox':
                widget = QCheckBox()
                widget.toggled.connect(self.argumentChanged)

            elif widgetType == 'QSpinBox':
                widget = QSpinBox()
                widget.valueChanged.connect(self.argumentChanged)

            widget.setProperty('widgetNumber', number)
            layout.addWidget(widget)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def argumentChanged(self, value):
        widget = self.sender()
        widgetNumber = widget.property('widgetNumber')
        print("The widget number", widgetNumber, 
            "that is a", self.widgetList[widgetNumber], 
            "has been modified! New value:", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening here:

```py
widget.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.argumentChanged(widgetNumber, widget.isChecked()))
```

is that `widgetNumber` is the same variable used in the enclosing `for` loop. By the time the `widget.stateChanged` signal is emitted, the aforementioned `for` loop has already ended (obviously), and `widgetNumber` is `3`.

> `lambda widgetNumber: self.argumentChanged(widgetNumber, widget.value()))`
>
> but the situation becomes stranger: when increasing the value of a SpinBox, the widget number is increasing, and vice-versa when decreasing it.

That's because the [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) signal passes the new value's integer value into your function/slot as the first argument (the `widgetNumber` parameter), which is then passed into `self.argumentChanged`.

In order to keep the value of `widgetNumber` to what it was during each iteration of the loop, you need to use `widgetNumber` as the default argument of the [lambda] function. Default arguments are evaluated when the function is first defined, not each time it is called, so you can access what `widgetNumber` was at the time of the [lambda] function during each iteration of the loop.

Note that you need to use a nested function. If you try to just have one function with a default argument, the argument will be set as the widget's changed value, since Qt5 passes it as the first argument.

The outer function, which is the one with `widgetNumber` as its default argument, simply defines an inner function, and returns that (without calling it). It doesn't matter if they're lambda functions or not. Having nested lambdas is just difficult to read.

It's pretty confusing, but have a play around with this:

```py
    def __init__(self, widgetList):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.widgetList = widgetList
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        for widgetNumber in range(len(widgetList)):
            
            if widgetList[widgetNumber] == 'QCheckBox':
                widget = QCheckBox()
                
                # A normal function with a nested lambda function
                def handle_state_changed(default_arg=widgetNumber):
                    return lambda state: print(f"QCheckBox state changed to {state}. default_arg (aka widgetNumber) = {default_arg})")
                
                widget.stateChanged.connect(handle_state_changed())
            
            elif widgetList[widgetNumber] == 'QSpinBox':
                widget = QSpinBox()
                
                # A normal function nested within another normal function
                # Whether they are lambda functions or not doesn't matter
                def handle_value_changed(default_arg=widgetNumber):
                    def inner(value):
                        print(f"QSpinBox value changed to {value}. default_arg (aka widgetNumber) = {default_arg})")
                    
                    return inner
                
                widget.valueChanged.connect(handle_value_changed())
            
            layout.addWidget(widget)
            
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

See also [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)